# Return a promise variable ouside the promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, promise

I need to get outside from the promise the value of a variable  but I can't because the scope of that. In my case i'm using Sequelize to save data to a SQL database but I wanna do with classes and the `dataToReturn` I receive with the promise after second `save`

```
.post('/', (req, res) =>  {
  const event = new Event(Events, Data, req.body)
  event.save()
  res.status(201).json("HERE I NEED THE 'dataToReturn' from the promise")
})
```

and this is my Class Event

```
class Event {

    constructor(Events, Data, Event) {
        this._Data = Data,
        this._Events = Events
        this._Event = Event
    }

    save() {
        this._Data.build(this._Event.Data).save().then((res) =>
            this._Events.build({
                name: this._Event.name,
                date: this._Evento.fecha,
                photo1: this._Event.photo1,
                photo2: this._Event.photo2,
                idData: res.dataValues.id
            }).save().then((dataToReturn) => "???")) <-- dont know what to do here
        return dataToReturn    <-- I want to return that variable but I cant because scopes
    }
```

What do you recommend?
I'm lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   class Event {
        /**  
        * Same code
        */
    save() {            
        return this._Data.build(this._Event.Data).save().then((res) =>
                this._Events.build({
                    name: this._Event.name,
                    date: this._Evento.fecha,
                    photo1: this._Event.photo1,
                    photo2: this._Event.photo2,
                    idData: res.dataValues.id
                })).save();
    }
```

Then use `then`in your route:

```
.post('/', (req, res) =>  {
  const event = new Event(Events, Data, req.body)
  event.save().then((dataToReturn) => {
   res.status(201).json(dataToReturn);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to do something like that with the return in `save()` and putting in a variable `event.save`, something like this `var ans = event.save()` and then `res.status(201).json(ans)` but didnt work. Thank you for your help. It worked very well :D

Answer (score 1):

Writing this on mobile so it won't look the best..

Remove the then in your event. Remove the return statement. In your route do:

```
return event.save().then(results => res.status(200).json(results));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to do something like that with the return in `save()` and putting in a variable `event.save`, something like this `var ans = event.save()` but didnt work. Thank you for your time and help, I appreciate a lot. Im going to give best answer to GlebkaF just because its better explained and it will helps more people. Thank you again. :)